# Need to update AWS ELB name in aws console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

Is there any way to update ELB name from AWS console or AWS cli.

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/update-environment.html  does this help ?

Answer (score 1):

ELB/ALB/NLB names can't be edited after the balancer is created.

You'll need to create a new balancer, associate it with the same targets, change any DNS records pointing to the old balancer so that they point to the new balancer, and eventually delete the old balancer.